# functional equation$X$ and $X^c$ are convex, then they are half-spaces -- A simple proof

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, linear-transformations, convex-analysis

Consider the   $R^n$ space. Let non-empty sets $X$ and $X^c$ be both convex. Let $X$ be closed.

Prove there exists a unique (unit) vector $v$ that separates $X$ and $X^c$:

$x\cdot v\geq c \iff x\in  X$

$x\cdot v< c \iff x\in X^c$.

---

A unit vector is any vector that $|v|=1$.

---

Comment: This can be taken as a simple special case of hyperplane separating theorem (HST) that gives both sufficient and necessary (unique) separating vector.

Comparing this question and HST, there are two main differences: first this question requires the vector to be unique. Second, this question requires the condition to be "$\iff$" rather than one-directional "$\implies$".

Overall, the set-up is much simpler than the set-up of HST. So do we have a simple proof (preferably without invoking the HST)?

Comment: I think that something is missing here. First of all, both $X$ and $X^c$ need to be nonempty. Second, one cannot find $v$ for $X = (-\infty, 1]$ in $\mathbb R^1$. Finally: Try to check which sets $X$ satisfy that both $X$ and $X^c$ are convex.

Comment: @gerw Very useful comment I am trying to update the question. Could you please elaborate more on your last sentence? I guess, if both $X$ and $X^c$ are convex, then they are some sort of "linear set" or "half space"?

Comment: Yes, they must be half spaces (since you want to prove that they are half spaces).

Comment: @gerw This statement seems very very obvious but I don't a simple proof for this. The only ways I can think of is to invoke the separating hyperplane theorem, or something even more complicated.